# What format is this in?

Tags: json

What format is this request in?

"customer_id=5&products%5B0%5D%5Barticle_id%5D=4099&products%5B0%5D%5Bquantity%5D=1&products%5B0%5D%5Btotal_price%5D=0"

is there a way to automatically convert JSON or normal text into this format?

Comment: Is this a part of an url? Like www.sampleurl.com?customer_id=5&products%5B0...

Comment: This looks like a URL encoding. decoding with that results in: ```customer_id=5&products[0][article_id]=4099&products[0][quantity]=1&products[0][total_price]=0```. Converting from json should be obvious from there. Also, please read the help section on asking questions...

Comment: If you are using js, you can convert json object to string and replace ":" with "=" , "," with "&" and remove "{" and "}" then url encode.

Comment: i didn't get this out of a URL which confused me. is there any way to generate this out of json ?

Comment: Give more specification about your problem

Comment: ah ok thank you guys for your help

Comment: I gave an answer with the information given however JSON will require more information. What format is the JSON in? Where did you find this string to begin with?

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to take a JSON formatted information into an API that will make a POST request. The POST request has to be in this format so I have to convert it somehow. The JSON is like this : [{
    "customer_id": "5",
    "products": [
      {
        "article_id": 4099,
        "quantity": 1,
        "total_price": 0
      }
    ]
  }]

Answer (score 0):

This request string appears to be encoded for a URL/URI.

You can use [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) to see the original string. For example:

```
var s = "customer_id=5&products%5B0%5D%5Barticle_id%5D=4099&products%5B0%5D%5Bquantity%5D=1&products%5B0%5D%5Btotal_price%5D=0";
var original = decodeURIComponent(s);
```

This will yield the following:

```
"customer_id=5&products[0][article_id]=4099&products[0][quantity]=1&products[0][total_price]=0"
```

To convert to this format you can use the inverse function called [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on the original string.